# Spray Marshalling Custom Objects

Tags: marshalling, spray, spray-json

I'm trying to marshal some custom objects to JSON in one of my responses and can't seem to get the logic right. I suspect this is a straight forward issue, but I just can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

I have the following which is fine...

```
case class MyKeyResponse(success:Boolean, key:String, 
  key_id:Int, key_description:String)
object MyKeyJsonResponseProtocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat4(AppKeyResponse)
}
```

I then declare the following which is meant to wrap a collection of the above MyKey objects which are returned from a DB query...

```
case class MyKeysResponse(success:Boolean, appKeys:Seq[MyKey])
object MyKeysJsonResponseProtocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat2(AppKeysResponse)
}
```

However I get the following errors...

```
not enough arguments for method jsonFormat2: 
(implicit evidence$4: …   MyKeysJsonResponseProtocols.JF[Boolean],     
implicit evidence$5: …MyKeysJsonResponseProtocols.JF[Seq[…   
MyKeys.AppKey]], implicit evidence$6: ClassManifest[…
MyKeysResponse])spray.json.RootJsonFormat[…MyKeysResponse]. Unspecified 
value parameters evidence$5, evidence$6.    MyKeysResponse.scala
```

and marshalling errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does `JsonFormat[MyKey]` exist and is it in scope?

Comment: Hi, therein lies part of my confusion too. Should I be declaring a custom marshaller here?

Comment: Yes, you should. Because you need to marshall `MyKey` first in order to marshall `MyKeysResponse`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample custom marshaller? Do I essentially need to implement the read and write methods in the case classes companion object?

Comment: Okay there is a little misunderstanding here. You just need a marshaller, it may or may not be custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was actually fairly straight forward and a lesson learned!
Each of my marshallers were using the same same implicit variable name...

```
object MyJsonResponseProtocol1 extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat2(...)
}

object MyJsonResponseProtocol2 extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat2(...)
}
```

and so on... They were obviously conflicting when I imported them. So I just renamed them.